# Wordpress website home page is working but inner pages and post disappearing after a moment

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i have already disabled all the plugins, update wordpress to latest version and using following htaccess.

```
   # BEGIN WordPress

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    # END WordPress
```

please check :  http://raghavlpg.com/?page_id=14

please let me know, what should do, to resolve this issue.
Thankyou

Comment: Please save permalinks from admin section and after saving it check once.

Comment: @KushalShah, i changed permalinks but not working.

Comment: Can you please share your error when you access inner page and posts ?

Comment: Please check this link http://raghavlpg.com/?page_id=14, page loads and after a moment page disappeared automatically.